# ACF Update Field function is not updating any data in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, advanced-custom-fields

I have created 2 custom fields in ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) for posts. The first one is **date** and the another is **volume**. The **volume** field should be able to get data from the **date** field based on the **year**. But, nothing is getting updated.

Here is the code:

```php
function UpdateVolumeField(){
    $post_id = false;
    $date_field = get_field('date_created', $post_id);
    $volume_field = get_field('volume', $post_id);

    //Calculation
    $year = date_format(date_create($date_field), 'Y');
    $vol  = 0;
    for($i=2010; $i<=$year ;$i++) {
        $vol += 1;
    }
    update_field('volume' ,$vol, $post_id);
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateVolumeField');
```

'date_created' is the field for date and 'volume' should be updated based on 'date_created' year.

When selecting a date in 'date_created' field and updating the post, the 'volume' field should be automatically updated, which can be seen when reloading the page. Here the 'volume' field will be starting from 2010 and hence forth. But nothing is getting updated.

What am I doing wrong (all plugins are updated to the latest versions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, The post ID `$post_id` variable should be included as a function argument (dynamic variable) mandatory for `acf/save_post'` hook, instead of including it statically inside your function with `false` value, allowing to retrieve 'date_created' and 'volume' fields values from the post, and allowing to update 'volume' field value.

Try the following revisited code instead:

```php
// Including missing $post_id function argument variable
function UpdateVolumeField( $post_id ){
    $date_field   = get_field('date_created', $post_id);
    $volume_field = get_field('volume', $post_id);

    //Calculation
    $year = date_format(date_create($date_field), 'Y');
    $vol  = 0;
    
    for($i = 2010; $i <= $year ;$i++) {
        $vol += 1;
    }
    
    remove_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateVolumeField'); // unhook to avoid infinit loop
    
    update_field('volume' ,$vol, $post_id); // Update 'volume' field
    
    add_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateVolumeField'); // rehook after updating
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateVolumeField');
```

It should better work now.

Comment: Thanks Bro, The Code is fine. One thing that was still making problem is the date, It shows 1970. But, I finally fixed it. So, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

You must Including missing `$post_id` function argument variable

```
function UpdateVolumeField( $post_id ){
    $date_field   = get_field('date_created', $post_id);
    $volume_field = get_field('volume', $post_id);

    $year = date_format(date_create($date_field), 'Y');
    $vol  = 0;
    
    for($i = 2010; $ <= $year ;$i++) {
        $vol += 1;
    }
    
    remove_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateVolumeField'); 
    
    update_field('volume' ,$vol, $post_id); 
    
    add_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateVolumeField'); 
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateVolumeField');
```